# Find value of axis in series

Tags: vb.net, excel, charts, series, points

I'd like to know how to find the value of the X axis, where the X and Y axes cross. The result is to be displayed in a cell. VB is optional.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ON19.png)
[image: Example]
Where the arrow points is the value I would like to get.
From where the `60` in the Y axis crosses the points, I'd like to get the Y axis.

Comment: That datapoint is at 59.44... etc. Imagine the points were connected via lines. I need the X axis value of where X and Y meet (if X is 60). Sorry if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: What I mean is, I want the value of X where Y is 60. Which would be something around 40 (where the red arrow is).

Comment: I've edited the chart image if that makes things more clear.